# Weaviate - How to create a vector using "text2vec-transformers" module?

Tags: weaviate

How to create a vector using "text2vec-transformers" module? I want to use "nearVector" method but there is no way to create vector using "text2vec-transformers" module. I am using this module as my default vectorizer.

I have searched whole documentation of weaviate but not able to find any answer.

Answer (score 2):

a couple of things. The page @hsm207 linked to describes `text2vec-transformers` modules.

The `text2vec-transformers` modules are for ingesting data while creating vectors at import time, and providing a way to provide text inputs for queries so they can be vectorized.

If you provide the input object to the right class, and have that class set up to use the `text2vec-xxx` module as its vectorizer, it'll create vectors at import time.

To see this in action, check out the [End-to-End Quickstart](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/quickstart/end-to-end). And there's also a Bring Your Own Vectors guide too, if you want to use your own vectors.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Thank you.